Identify if a request is ByPassing CDN (.NET)
Is there a way using .NET to determine if a visitor is bypassing CDN?  Is there a property or method I can determine if they're using say the IP of my server to access the site?
One way to be to determine if the IP and check it against their list but I don't have all the CDN's IPs.

What does "bypassing CDN" mean?

Isn't the idea of a CDN that those requests never reach your ASP.NET website at all?

That is correct @Uwe Keim but I'm certain some visitors are going direct to the origin server instead of going to the CDN and I want to identify how they're doing it so I can block them.

Sounds like a misconfiguration to me, if your CDN files are also stored elsewhere. Why not simply delete them on the origin server and have them on your CDN server only?
